# How to stretch Movie Clip according to user's touch coordinates?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have code like this:

```
touchX = e.stageX;
touchY = e.stageY;
```

I also have a player movieclip that I'm trying to make shoot lasers.  So I got the MovieClip to appear and rotate according to the player's location and the user's touchX and touchY.  How do I make the laser MovieClip stretch according to the distance between the player's coordinates and the touchX and touchY coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have the pivot point in the center of your laser clip. Calculate the distance between the player and the input.

```
var dx:Number = touchX - player.x; //Assuming SAME coordinate space
var dy:Number = touchY - player.y; // Else use localToGlobal
var halfdist:Number = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)/2;
```

Now scale your movieclip by distance.

```
   laser.width = halfdist;
```

Rotate your laser

```
var rot:Number = Math.atan2(dy,dx); 
laser.rotation = rot * (180*Math.PI);
```

Place your Laser by rotation:

```
 laser.x = Math.cos(rot) * halfdist + player.x;
 laser.y = Math.sin(rot) * halfdist + player.y;
```

Comment: This code is good, but edit it and change Math.Pi to math.PI, the i should be capital.  Also, when I run this code, the scaleX and scaleY seem to change.

Comment: Well im only touching the Width though. scaleY shouldn't be affected

Comment: EDIT the height changes because the object is rotating...

Comment: Rotation shouldn't affect the scale.

Comment: Weird... I found out that as the object rotates, the object is now rotated and so the width becomes a different part of the scaling.

Comment: Then you are affecting the scaling elsewhere

Comment: I'm not effecting the scaling, it's just when you rotate the movieclip the width increase increases it from a new perspective.

Comment: Fixed!  I created a movieclip in the laser that has its own perspective of angle that cannot be changed from its root parent and changed the width of that.

Comment: @Abe You're right, width and height have effect on the bounding box. You can also try to calculate the ratio and apply it on scaleX.

Comment: ScaleX... good idea!

Comment: You could try  laser.scaleX = halfdist/100; instead of laser.width ( not sure if it will work, but to test it you have to put your laser back as it was )

Comment: I decided not to use scaleX, because if I wanted to flip it later or something....

Comment: you could store the width and height of the movieclip at rotation=0 in a variable for later reuse.